# how can i stop all submitted tasks on ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

i want to stop all the submitted tasks on an ExecutorService but i couldn't find a method to do it. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`ExecutorService.shutdownNow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

for example, var pool is an ExecutorService.

```
//start a task 
pool.execute(task);

//
try {
    pool.shutdown();
    if(!pool.awaitTermination(awaitTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){
        pool.shutdownNow();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    pool.shutdownNow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A deterministic shutdown for any task submitted to `ExecutorService` is possible only when the task itself is designed to respond to a external signal ( such as an Interruption on the thread running the task , or some other application designed flag ). `ExecutorService` itself only helps in as much as it will raise these signals for you ( when you call its `shutdown()` and `shutdownNow()` methods ) and notify all running tasks. If you want to be able to shutdown all tasks ( including the ones which are already running and not yet finished ) then design these tasks to have a cancellation policy.